# AverageIF for all the rows that match the condition but the last one

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to calculate the average amount of the invoices that matches a certain criteria (invoices for particular company name, so averageif), but I want to exclude the last row from this calculation. That means that if there are 4 invoices matching "FACEBOOK", I want to calculate the average only for the first 3 ones and exclude the last one. How do I go about it?

Here is the formula that I have at the moment (it's working, but I don't know how to modify it to make it fit to my goal):

```
=AVERAGEIFS('Invoices'!$H:$H",'Invoices'!$F:$F",C2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
=average(query('Invoices'!$F:$H, "Select H where F ='"&C2&"' limit "&sumproduct('Invoices'!F:F=C2)-1))
```